# Retrofit2 with RxJava,call a same server api many times at the same time

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2

I try to use Retrofit2 with RxJava but I'm a newbie with RxJava & Retrofit.

I have a api like:

```
@POST("donSomething")
Observable<RespData> doSomeThing(@Body ReqData reqData);
```

And it may be called many times at the same time.

How many http request will be created , if I call the `doSomeThing` many times at the same time?

What Should I do if I just want it create one Http request (with RxJava)?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. I bet you need to share that observable with multiple part of the code and you do not want it to be called many times unless you explicitly ask for a refresh. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

one http call will be performed each time you **subscribe** to your `Observable`.

For example :

```
             // nothing will happens, you haven't subscribe to your observable
             yourservice.doSomething(request);
```

If you subscribe to your `Observable`then Retrofit will perform an http call :

```
             // one http call will be performed as soon as the subscribe method is call on your Observable
             yourservice.doSomething(request).subscribe();
```

One http call will be performed each time you subscribe :

```
             // do nothing (in term of http call)
             Observable<RespData> obs = yourservice.doSomething(request);

             // first call
             obs.subscribe();

             // second call
             obs.subscribe();
```

If you want to perform one http call instead of several, you may want to perform network call collapsing. If so, you can look at Hystrix which perform this: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#RequestCollapsing

Comment: Hystrix is interesting, and RequestCollapsing too... but this imply you CAN use Hystrix. Which usually is not the case. I think that it should be a solution with RxJava (and I hope there is).

Comment: you can look at how hystrix do this, as it use RxJava. (And may use it to do the request collapsing)